# nosql cassandra - how to create update query based on select

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cql

I tried to create a query to update the number of rows of specific table:

```
UPDATE Albums (NumOfphotos) 
VALUES (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM photos 
    WHERE AlbumName='nature'
) 
WHERE AlbumName='nature';
```

This does not seem to be the right syntax,
what is the right way to do it (maybe by autokey)?

Answer (score 2):

This type of query is deliberately not supported by Cassandra nor CQL.

If you review the [datastax CQL documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_reference/update_r.html) for update you will see that the "where specification" only takes either a primary key or a IN(keys) clause:

```
primary key name = key_value
primary key name IN (key_value ,...)
```

So your best bet is to do a

```
SELECT * FROM photos WHERE AlbumName='nature';
```

followed by updates to set the correct values.